# Color each point in different color Threejs

Tags: javascript, colors, three.js, points, vertex

I have points and color (r, g, b). I need to use one color for one point.
I did this

```
    const vertices = new Float32Array(data.points);
    const colors = new Float32Array(data.colors)
    geometry.setAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( vertices, 3 ) );
    geometry.setAttribute( 'color', new THREE.BufferAttribute( colors, 3 ) );
    const material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({color: colors});
    const pointCloud = new THREE.Points( geometry, material)
    this.scene.clear();
    this.scene.add( pointCloud );
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
```

In this way, I get white points. If I use:

```
const material = new THREE.PointsMaterial( { vertexColors: true } );
```

I got this error:

```
[.WebGL-0x2e2bb1a84c00]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 1
```

Comment: looks like your `colors` data contains values of integers in range 0..255, whereas it has to be floats in range 0..1. `vertexColors: true` is a correct option.

Comment: One option is to cast all values to the range 0..1, something like this `data.colors.map(d => {return d / 255.0})`. Another option is to set the third parameter of `BufferAttribute` to `true`: `new THREE.BufferAttribute( colors, 3, true )`, if `colors` is `UInt8Array`.

Comment: Thank you! I tried both variants, but I also have this error: [.WebGL-0x2e2bb2456c00]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 1

Comment: Then better to provide a working code snippet or an editable working live code example, that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Make sure your `colors` and `points` arrays are the same length. For this scenario, there is a one-to-one match between vertex and colors values.

Comment: @Helen could you share the code where you create `data.points` and `data.colors`? It sounds like they're not of the same length.

Comment: You are right!
Thank you a lot:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you:)
First of all, I need to use colors from 0 to 1 (not 0 to 255). Then I needed to get arrays with the same length. And I needed to use { vertexColors: true }.